# How to start a servlet multiple time with different configuration on a same JVM

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets

We want to launch a same war multiple time (on different path of course) in a same tomcat instance but with different configuration. Is it possible?

The configuration is application specific.

What will be the best way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "different configuration"?

Comment: I prefer use zookeeper for instantiating multiple instances. But really what type of configuration are you modifying.

Comment: Just rename the war, change config and restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JNDI in your code to access configuration resources (DataSource connections, Mail sessions, or other resources), it is immediate: The war you deploy has only code with JNDI references, which the deployer will satisfy on every deployment made.